# Documentum - Hashkey Differed between DFC and DFS

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs

I am doing POC in Documentum. while trying to get the content of the XML files. hash key differed between DFC and DFS..
Reason is

```
> <?dctm original_encoding=UTF-8 has_bom=falseconfig_locator=09de75d180000478?>
```

this line is missing in DFS. 
Can anyone help me to find out the reason?

Comment: Is there an application set in your Documentum repository to view XML files?  Just curious.